# Java android webview extract an iframe src http

Tags: android, webview

I asked a question before but the wording was all wrong and I don't think it explained what I really wanted to do so here goes;

I have a webview in my app that access a website that I do not own or run, the website has a iframe with the following information:

iframe id="download_file" scrolling="no" src="http://www13.online-convert.com/download-file/41ffbb25dc972bdee4abc02ea1164fea/converted-df4a80e3.mp3">/iframe

Its a link that downloads a file, however the android webview doesn't allow me to click the link and download the file.

I have now added a button to my app, what I want the button to do is the following;
1 - extract the src http address from the iframe (http://www13.online-convert.com/download-file/41ffbb25dc972bdee4abc02ea1164fea/converted-df4a80e3.mp3)
2 - save that http address as a string that I can use.
3 - download the file.

The issue is I have know idea how to use javascript or a simple java code that can use my webview to locate that http address and save it as a string.

I have tried several tutorials, I have looked every where for a answer, is this even possible what I am trying to do?

Please any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
Create a file in your assets folder named sample.html

```
<html>

<a href="http://www13.online-convert.com/download-file/41ffbb25dc972bdee4abc02ea1164fea/converted-df4a80e3.mp3" >Link<a/>

</html>
```

and your activity class onCreate function use this codes.

```
WebView webview;
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
```